# How can I find the device uuid's of all connected devices through a command line script?

Tags: iphone, ios, uuid

I am running automated tests on iOS devices.  I want to not have to always have all devices connected.  So I want to find all device id's and then only start the process of building, deploying, and running tests if that device is connected.

So my question is, how can I find the device uuid's of all connected devices through a shell script?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/vaskas/udidetect

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Edit:

`instruments` command is now deprecated, you should run instead

```
xcrun xctrace list devices
```

Previous answer:

If you have **Xcode** installed, you can use **Instruments** to get all known devices also. With

```
instruments -s devices
```

Comment: +1 for an answer that allows parsing. This prints out the device list in a single-line format. alternately, one can also use ios-deploy -c (which admittedly is not an Apple-only solution)

Comment: Does this command still works? According to the Xcode docs `instruments -s`just lists the available templates which is the result I get when I execute the command mentioned above, but that is not a device list.

Comment: The output list should include your device list.

Comment: @Quanlong can we save this devices list to a variable. I need to save this in a variable and search a device from this list. I am using shell script.

Comment: how to get UDID of simulator as well along with device ?

Comment: This one gives list of attached simulators as well.

Comment: Using `xcrun xctrace list devices` if you have Xcode 12.1 installed.

Comment: The new `xcrun xctrace list devices` isn't quite good to work with because you cannot easily `grep` simulator vs real devices because it shows 2 tables instead of the device type in brackets. I'd recommend stick to instruments for better flexibility until it's completely deleted...

Comment: `xcrun xctrace list devices` doesn't work for me here in 6/2023. It returns the wrong devices. Now I use `ios-deploy -c -t 1 -W -C -j`

Answer (score 26):

The answer from @KKendall set me on the right path.  Here's a version with a single sed expression:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType | sed -n -E -e '/(iPhone|iPad)/,/Serial/s/ *Serial Number: *(.+)/\1/p'
```

Comment: how to get UDID of simulator as well along with device ?

Answer (score 21):

install [ideviceinstaller](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller) on Mac OS X via brew command:
`brew install ideviceinstaller`

then `idevice_id -l` will work from terminal

Comment: also this command shows device which is not connected and "instruments -s devices" shows it like (null) [1112314227ead6e1132b9c20efd74412329e77b6]

Comment: returns no result for me.

Answer (score 14):

I found a similar question about [using multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195736/instrument-multiple-device-execution/12909217#12909217) here is my form of the answer that helped me:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 i=0
 for line in $(system_profiler SPUSBDataType | sed -n -e '/iPad/,/Serial/p' -e '/iPhone/,/Serial/p' | grep "Serial Number:" | awk -F ": " '{print $2}'); do
    UDID=${line}
    echo $UDID
    udid_array[i]=${line}
    i=$(($i+1))
 done

 cnt=${#udid_array[@]}
 for ((i=0;i<cnt;i++)); do
    echo ${udid_array[i]}
 done
```

Comment: It looks that answer not actual right now because new apple devices have ids with "-" like 00008027-0001713202E8002E  but  system_profiler shows id without "-" : Serial Number: 000080270001713202E8002E

Answer (score 8):

Also [ios-deploy](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy) can be used:

```
ios-deploy -c | grep -oE 'Found ([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)' | sed 's/Found //g'
```

Comment: This works, but will include newlines in some cases. Adding " | tr -d \'\r\n\'" fixes that.

Comment: Works best for me in 6/2023 since `xcrun xctrace list devices` is broken, returning the wrong devices. Now I use `ios-deploy -c -t 1 -W -C -j`

Answer (score 4):

If you have XCode go to Window > Devices & Simulators. On that page, any connected device will display along with other IDs and stats on your device. This will also connect to devices over WIFI.