# How can I get iOS device informations from terminal connected to real device?

Tags: java, ios, automation, appium-ios

For automation of iOS app in appium/Java purpose, I need to get device name, UDID, bundle ID, platform version from terminal or from some script\s so that I don't have to hardcode these values in my tests. Main reason I wanted to do this is because we have lots of real devices and don't want to manage all those properties instead i want to get all those properties before my tests starts. Can somebody help me?

I found `idevice_id -l` which can get me UDID. I want kind of similar or more efficient approach. Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: i would suggest you to create a properties file having all the devices capabilities and externalize and call them in ur java program, thats the best practise for a framework instead of fetching each time from terminal

Comment: check this thread for UDID.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237354/how-can-i-find-the-device-uuids-of-all-connected-devices-through-a-command-line

Comment: Thanks Guys. @karthick23 what do you mean by externalize? I am interested in your idea.