# Is there a way to run several Scripts continuously in Instruments (iOS) UI Automation?

Tags: instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, automated-tests, xcode-instruments

Whenever I try to do UI Automation in Instruments (iPhone simulator) by Apple, I have several different scripts to run. The problem is that I need to sit back and run each script when the former one ends. I wonder then what's the use of Automation if still I need to sit and run each script after the other.

Can anyone tell me (or is there) a way to run more than one script with just one click? and don't need to run record button for every script?

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem. According to the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html): "You can create as many scripts as you like, but you can run only one at a time."

So what I tried to bundle all the scripts into one by importing them:

```
# import "test1.js"
# import "test2.js"
```

Save this as a separate script (e.g. "testAll.js") and run this one.

Comment: It says "import files not found(null)"... Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this error is because your test should be on the same folder, so maybe you need to include a path for Test from another folder

Answer (score 4):

YES !!! You can run a test suite with all your script.
For example you can write a script for each screen in your app, and after created a test suite to run all the script or if you prefer only run a couple of this scripts. 
You need uses the sentencie #import “script1.js” for each scripts.
Example:

```
//import all scripts that you need to include
#import "screen1.js"
#import "screen2.js"
#import "screen3.js"

function Main(){

// Tests:       
     TestScreen1(); // this method is on "screen1.js"
     TestScreen2(); // this method is on "screen2.js"
     TestScreen3(); // this method is on "screen3.js"

 };

// call to function Main 

Main();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just run them from the command line - Place all your scripts in a folder and create a sh script

Example:

```
FILES=`find <<insert script location>> -iregex '.*\(js\)' `
for script in $FILES
do
    echo "Processing $script

instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /"<<insert app location>>/App.app" -e UIASCRIPT $script -e UIARESULTSPATH "<<insert Result path>>" >> "results.txt"

done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can launch instruments from the command line, thus you can use a bash script to run your tests in batch mode. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash    
instruments -t  "$UIA_TRACETEMPLATE_PATH" "$APP_PATH" -e UIASCRIPT "$SCRIPT1_PATH" -e UIARESULTSPATH "$OUTPUT1_PATH"
instruments -t  "$UIA_TRACETEMPLATE_PATH" "$APP_PATH" -e UIASCRIPT "$SCRIPT2_PATH" -e UIARESULTSPATH "$OUTPUT2_PATH"
#etc
```

The advantage of this approach is that the tests are separated, since the bash script restarts instruments before every test. Even is your first test aborts execution will continue with the next test.

Answer (score 1):

As I know UIAutomation is a single process application and can't run several tests/devices in parallel.

You can read more here: [Instruments automation trace only allows one target connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691598/instruments-automation-trace-only-allows-one-target-connection)

Also I tried to run automation under different users but without success. You can use virtual machines or several mac mini for your task.